# Is it correct for a list of html elements to have their own <h*> hierarchy?

Tags: html, hierarchy

Semantically speaking, is it correct for such a situation:

```
<h1>page title</h1>
<p>some content</p>

<h2>group title</h2>
<ul class="card-list">
    <li>
       <div class="card">
         <h2>card title</h2>
         <h3>card subtitle</h3>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div class="card">
         <h2>another card title</h2>
         <h3>card subtitle</h3>
       </div> 
    </li>
    <li><!-- etc. --></li>
</ul>
```

to have a list of elements with their own hierarchy, regardless the context they appear?

Comment: It is entirely valid, yes. I'm not sure how "correct" can be answered. (Heading elements do *not* create or participate in any explicit hierarchy.)

Comment: @user2864740 I've always thought only 'flow' elements should go inside `<li>` tags, but I admit my basis for that lacks references; except my own upturned nose! hehe